# SQL Cloud Proxy keeps restarting the connection when used as a sidecar

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, sidecar, google-cloud-proxy

I'm having a weird issue with SQL Proxy when I use it as a sidecar with my deployment on my Kubernetes cluster. In summary, it keeps closing the connection for the client then opening a new one right away without causing any fatal exception!

#### My Deployment

I have a deployment object that has 2 images, (1) **Spring Boot App** and (2) **SQL Cloud Proxy**. I use SQL Proxy to access the database from a different GCP project (I have my reasons). All requests to the exposed services from this deployment work fine, but I keep getting errors in the logs stating that connection is being closed from SQL Proxy and established again!
[image]

#### My deployment YAML file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
        log_forwarding: "true"
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: artifactory-secret
      nodeSelector:
        apps: run
      containers:
      - name: db-proxy
        image: my-artifactory/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.17
        command:
          - "/cloud_sql_proxy"
          - "-instances=project:europe-north1:slm-preview=tcp:5432"
          - "-credential_file=/secrets/service_account.json"
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
        volumeMounts:
          - name: sql-proxy-sa-secret
            mountPath: /secrets/
            readOnly: true
        
      - image: my-artifactory/my-app/app:dev-c3235e9bf3473e61cb3c496e4fb2a69f4f54b07f
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: my-app
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
        env:
        - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: gcp_dev
        - name: SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION
          value: file:/config-repo/application.yml,file:/config-repo/core-service.yml
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: db-sercret
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8001
            protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            ephemeral-storage: "1Gi"
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            ephemeral-storage: "1Gi"
            memory: 1Gi
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 20
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/info
            port: 8001
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 60
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 2
        
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 8001
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 60
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 30
        # terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        # terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /config-repo
          name: config-repo-volume

      volumes:
      - name: sql-proxy-sa-secret
        secret:
          secretName: sa-sql-user
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: my-app-config
        name: config-repo-volume
```

#### What I'm looking for?

I'm trying to find a way to solve the issue of restarting the connection thousands of times a day! I did some research around if I can force the proxy not to reset the connection and keep it alive, but I found nothing!

I would appreciate your help guys!

Comment: Can you give a bit of information regariding the ammount of queries you are running towards the database? Also, are all the connections being inmediatly restarted?

Comment: This keeps happening with 1 connection in place (1 service) and even without running any query at that time. It just keeps restarting non-stop!

Answer (score 0):

Those logs imply that your application is closing/reopening connections. The Proxy seems to be working correctly in that it notices the old connection closing (and prints a log about it) and notices a new connection (and prints a log about it).

If you'd like to avoid this happening, you'll have to use connection pooling in your application, or between the application and the Proxy (e.g. using something like pgbouncer).

See this similar issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/539